# Scaling issue using icons in navbar

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have icons in a navbar using [materialize.css](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html). When the window falls below a certain threshold all icons are shifted to the top.
How can I prevent this shifting whithout hiding the icons on small screens?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6naew9h/15/). Notice how the icons are shifting upwards when the size of the frame gets smaller than 600px.

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">
      <i class="material-icons left">local_bar</i>
      Title
    </a>
    <ul class="right">
      <li><a><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) are used in your code (in `ghpages-materialize.css`), that means there are different styles for different screen (or window) sizes :

```
nav {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ee6e73;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    line-height: 56px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px)
nav, nav .nav-wrapper i, nav a.button-collapse, nav a.button-collapse i {
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 64px;
}
```

You can prevent this shifting by fixing the styles of each screen size. Chrome developper Tools can help you fixing this.

[image: Chrome Developper Tools]

You can add this to your `CSS` file to fix it (for All media) :

```
nav {
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 64px;
}

i.material-icons.left {
    line-height: 64px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the line height of the icon. See fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/b6naew9h/16/

```
.material-icons {
    line-height: 56px;
}
```

Comment: Alternative solution is to set the height of all nav elements to be the same as the navbar itself, then vertically center all the internal components if necessary.